# Hide page name in wordpress page title

Tags: wp-head, wp-title

In my pages  title I got for example "home-my title' and  'Books Archieves- my title',
I want to drop those prefixes so I have only on page (home) 'My title'  and on archive(category)  'Books- my title'.
that's what I got inside the `head`: `<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to Edit your theme's Header.php  tag. 
You will see necessary codes there. You can modify to fit your needs. 
However, If you need more specific help, please paste your themes header.php here.

Thanks

Comment: this what I have inside the head 
<?php wp_head(); ?>
then starts the body

Comment: Nothing more than wp_head ? Is there no <title> tag ?

Comment: no that's what I got between the <head> session, besides 
for my home page I'm using a static custom page

Comment: Probably title is being called within wp_head()  You should check function files for the exact code

Answer (score 0):

your are using yoast SEO plugin.  to modify how the page or archive pages' title  looks you need to modify the seo setting of the plugin   SEO > titles and metas